# Yii scope for models' filtering by relations condition

Tags: mysql, yii

I have model Group with `HAS_MANY` relation to `ScheduleElement`.
Need create scope for filtering Groups:
Group must be have minimal one `ScheduleElement` for all combinations of fields ScheduleElement's: week_number (1-2), week_day (1-7), `semester_id = 1`

Comment: Have you figured out how to do this in plain SQL?

Comment: If i had SQL, i'd do it myself :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution myself, source code: https://github.com/sc0rp1d/schedule/blob/e510ad72b95e9491af9ff2f5692d9b0e469140f7/models/Group.php#L95

```
public function filled($bool = true)
    {
    $schedule_table = ScheduleElement::model()->tableName();
    $semester = Semesters::model()->actual();
    $criteria = $this->getDbCriteria();
    $criteria->params[':semester_id'] = $semester->id;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
        for ($j = 1; $j <= 6; $j++) {
            $sql = "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `$schedule_table` 
                WHERE `$schedule_table`.`week_number` = $i 
                AND `$schedule_table`.`week_day` = $j 
                AND `$schedule_table`.`group_id` = `t`.`id` 
                AND `$schedule_table`.`semester_id` = :semester_id) " 
                . ($bool ? ">" : "=") . " 0";
            $criteria->addCondition($sql, $bool ? 'AND' : 'OR');
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: For future reference just add the code to the answer. Link only answers are considered bad answers.